# Ruby Gems or libraries for building those standard sortable, filterable, searchable tables of data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have to build one of those standard admin-y CRUD apps with tons sortable, searchable, filterable tables of data, like below:

[image: standard table of data]

Are there any popular or standard gems or libraries for building these things?  Something I can reuse and customize like a data table builder, instead of copying and pasting a bunch of view code and tweaking?

Answer (score 1):

Active Admin may serve your needs: http://activeadmin.info/

Note that it basically gives you a framework for your administration panel.